# Skanavi 2.003, Difference in answers, which is right?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Skanavi book i have a exercise to simplify an equation

$$\begin{align}
((\sqrt[4]{p} - \sqrt[4]{q})^{-2} + (\sqrt[4]{p} + \sqrt[4]{q})^{-2}) : \frac{\sqrt p + \sqrt q}{p-q}
\end{align}$$

### Solving:

#### Replacing:

$$ a =\sqrt[4]{p} $$
 $$ b=\sqrt[4]{q} $$

#### Equation is changed:

$$
((a - b)^{-2} + (a + b)^{-2}): \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^4-b^4}
$$

$$ A = ((a - b)^{-2} + (a + b)^{-2})$$ 
$$ B = \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^4-b^4}$$

$$ B =  \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^4-b^4} => B = \frac{a^2+b^2}{(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)} =>  B = \frac{1}{a^2 - b^2}$$

$$ A = ((a - b)^{-2} + (a + b)^{-2}) => A = \frac{1}{(a - b)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(a + b)^{2}} => A = \frac{(a + b)^2 + (a-b)^2}{(a^2 - 2ab + b^2)(a^2 + 2ab + b^2)} => A = \frac{a^2 + 2ab + b^2 + a^2 - 2ab + b^2}{a^4 + 2a^2b^2 + b^4 - 2a^2b - 4a^2b^2 - 2ab^2 + a^2b^2+2ab^2+b^4} => A =\frac{2a^2 + 2b^2}{a^4 - 2a^2b^2 + b^4} => A = \frac{2(a^2+b^2)}{(a^2-b^2)^2}$$

$$ A : B $$
$$ \frac{2(a^2+b^2)}{(a^2-b^2)^2} : \frac{1}{a^2 - b^2}  =  \frac{2(a^2+b^2)(a^2 - b^2)}{(a^2-b^2)^2} = \frac{2(a^2+b^2)}{(a^2-b^2)}$$

#### My Answer is:

$$
\frac{2(\sqrt p +\sqrt q)}{(\sqrt p-\sqrt q)}
$$

#### Books answer is:

$$
\frac{2(\sqrt p +\sqrt q)^2}{(p- q)}
$$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying your answer by $1=\frac {\sqrt p+\sqrt q}{\sqrt p+\sqrt q}$?

Comment: @MarkBennet, noo, because i think it isn't right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Mark said is exactly right.

$$
\frac{2(\sqrt p +\sqrt q)}{(\sqrt p-\sqrt q)} \\ = 
\frac{2(\sqrt p +\sqrt q)(\sqrt p + \sqrt q)}{(\sqrt p-\sqrt q)(\sqrt p + \sqrt q)} \\ = 
\frac{2(\sqrt p +\sqrt q)^2}{(\sqrt p)^2 - (\sqrt q)^2} \\ = 
\frac{2(\sqrt p +\sqrt q)^2}{p-q}
$$

Remember $(a+b)(a-b)= a^2 - b^2$. It's very useful for problems like this.

Comment: thanks @Deepak, but why i'm need to multiplying to get correct answer?

Comment: It's called "rationalising the denominator". It's a very common technique in this sort of problem. On the whole, you don't want to leave surds (radical terms) in the denominators of expressions. You're basically multiplying by 1 (as the numerator and denominator of that expression are the same), so you don't change the original value, but you make the expression look "nicer" (and also easier to work with later).

Comment: best answer for me, thanks)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have fourth roots you can do the following, to eliminate roots from the denominator.

$$\frac {2(a^2+b^2)}{a^2-b^2}=\frac {2(a^2+b^2)}{a^2-b^2}\cdot\frac {a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}=\frac {2(a^2+b^2)^2}{a^4-b^4}$$

Substitute your values into this and you will see that the two answers are equal to each other.

---

Alternatively, without any short cuts $$\frac{\sqrt p+\sqrt q}{\sqrt p-\sqrt q}-\frac {(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)^2}{p-q} =$$$$\frac {p\sqrt p+p\sqrt q-q\sqrt p-q\sqrt q-p\sqrt p-2p\sqrt q-q\sqrt p+p\sqrt q+2q\sqrt p+q\sqrt q}{(\sqrt p-\sqrt q)(p-q)}=0$$